# Problems following MS docs guides - giving my provider-hosted add-in the sharepoint look

Tags: development, csom, page-layout

I am following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/give-your-provider-hosted-add-in-the-sharepoint-look-and-feel) guide. The issue is that even though I did literally every single thing mentioned there multiple times the chrome_ctrl_container doesn't seem to load and the thing just exactly the same as before I touched it. The worst thing is that I don't really know how to troubleshoot this project, as the problem seems to be on the aspx side of things and when I set breakpoints there VS says they will never be reached. My wild guess would be that there is some issue with accessing _layouts/15/, but I can't know for sure. I'd really appreciate your help. Things would be much easier if I just knew how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

The add-in will load the CSS correctly if no issues, you could use developer tool to check.
[image] 
You could create a test add-in project from scratch and deploy to a developer site so you could debug, the github project configured ServiceBus for debugging.
[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is going on on the second screenshot? I'm not familiar with js. I have some guesses but I'd rather be certain.

Comment: Just a break point will be hit when debugging(in Visual Studio) the add-in in developer site.